# listener to or listener of

Tags: grammar, prepositions

May be it's a trivial question but I am not sure if it is right to say:

> I am an ardent **listener to** your podcast

or

> I am an ardent **listener of** your podcast.

The verb *listen* has the preposition *to*. But does this rule function in the case of the noun?

Comment: This is a good question.  I think we're getting tripped up by the fact that we _listen to_ something, but that's a red herring: in this sentence, I am not listening, I just _am_.  If we use a different verb, like _read_ and a different noun, like _reader_, the answer becomes much clearer: I'm a reader _of_ books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this rule doesn't apply to the noun.

Preps are used to "link" elements of a sentence. You are an ardent listener **in relation to** that podcast. So you get statements like these:

> **I am** an ardent **listener of** your podcast.
>
> **I'm** a big **fan of** trailer music.
>
> **I'm** a curious **follower of** theism.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find this example interesting:

"We've received a lot of complaints about the changes from regular listeners to the programme."

Cambridge Advanced Learner's

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example of the "of" choice](http://www.indyweek.com/arts/archives/2015/07/23/dance-review-this-american-life-meets-dance-theater-in-a-worthy-experiment-at-adf):

> Though *Three Acts, Two Dancers, One Radio Host* unfolds on Barnes’
>   territory, the stage, its three-act narrative structure is familiar to
>   **listeners of** *This American Life*.

*This American Life* is a radio program and a podcast, well known in the U.S.

To my U.S. ear, "of" sounds right.  On the other hand, the Cambridge Advanced Learner's example would feel right to me when listening to a BBC podcast.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can *listen to* a sound, but you cannot really be a *listener to* sound.  You have to be a *listener of* sound.

*Listen* is a verb describing an action, so it can be targeted or aimed toward an object.  *To* is the preposition that expresses that.

*Listener* is a noun describing an instance of a type of person - "one who listens" (this is what the *-er* suffix means).  So it can *be* the object of a verb or preposition, but it cannot really directly *have* an object.

Also, using *to X* in the manner like *listener to sound* means *according to X* and X can be a concrete person or abstract noun.

> I am a good person to Jane = I am a good person according to Jane.
>
> I am an enemy to uncleanliness = I am an enemy according to uncleanliness.
>
> I am a listener to your podcast = I am a listener according to your podcast.

But since the example is "listener" and "podcast" - and "podcast" is obviously something someone listens to, it's likely to be something that is not noticed or misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

IMO they both can be used with a slightly different meaning:

> I’m a listener of your podcast.

Implies the understanding of the possessiveness by using the preposition **of**, that is I’m a listener of the music that belongs to your podcast, while

> I’m a listener to your podcast.

Implies the direction by using the preposition **to**, that is I’m a listener of the music that is broadcasted from your podcast.

Comment: "I’m a listener of your podcast." also has a meaning that you listen to the podcast on a regular basis, as in "I’m a *fan* of your podcast.

Comment: @user3169, thanks a lot for your input! As a native, that you confirm the use of “**to** the podcast” is very valuable for me.